# Brauer group of a field and norms

Tags: galois-theory, galois-cohomology, brauer-group

For $a,b \in K^\times$ the symbol $(a,b)$ denotes the element of the Brauer group of $K$ represented by the $2$-cocycle on the absolute Galois group $G_K$ of $K$ sending $(g_1,g_2)$ to 
$$
\sqrt{a}^{\varphi(g_1)+\varphi(g_2)-\varphi(g_1g_2)}
$$
where
$$
\varphi(g)= \begin{cases}
0 & \mathrm{if \ } g\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{b} \\
1 & \mathrm{if \ } g\sqrt{b}=-\sqrt{b}
\end{cases}
$$

By abuse of notation we let $(a,b)$ denote this $2$-cocycle.

Now $(a,b)=(b,a)$ and thus $(a,b)=1$ if and only if $a$ is a norm from $K(\sqrt{b})/K$ if and only if $b$ is a norm from $K(\sqrt{a})/K$.

Doing some calculations I saw that the possible values for $\varphi(g_1)+\varphi(g_2)-\varphi(g_1g_2)$ are either $0$ or $2$, so $(g_1,g_2)$ is sent either to $1$ or $a$ (it's sent to $a$ when $g_1 \sqrt{b}=g_2 \sqrt{b}=-\sqrt{b}$).

Suppose now $a$ is a norm from $K(\sqrt{b})/K$ i.e. $a=x^2-by^2$ for some $x,y \in K$. Define now $\phi: G_K \to \overline{K}$ to be such that $\phi(g)=x+\sqrt{b}y$ if $g\sqrt{b}=-\sqrt{b}$ and $\phi(g)=1$ otherwise. Then we can see that 
$$
(a,b)(g_1,g_2)=\frac{g_1 \phi(g_2) \cdot \phi(g_1)}{\phi(g_1g_2)}
$$
i.e. $(a,b)$ is a $2$-coboundary.

Now suppose $\exists \ \phi : G_K \to \overline{K}$ such that 
$$
(a,b)(g_1,g_2)=\frac{g_1 \phi(g_2) \cdot \phi(g_1)}{\phi(g_1g_2)}
$$

Now $\mathrm{Gal}(K(\sqrt{b})/K)$ is generated by some $g \in G_K$ and we have 
$$
a=(a,b)(g,g)=\frac{g \phi(g) \cdot \phi(g)}{\phi(g^2)}=g \phi(g) \cdot \phi(g)
$$
and so $N_{K(\sqrt{b})/K)}(\phi(g))=a$

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have modified your original question in which, if I remember well, the commutativity of the symbol $<a, b>$ was absent. But your definitions - of the Brauer group, of the symbol $<a,b>$ - are not precise enough. And besides, it does not appear in your proof that the equivalences between the 4 properties are not of the same nature. Let me try to explain.

1) **Symmetry of the normic property**, namely *a* is a norm from $K(\sqrt b)$ iff *b* is a norm from $K(\sqrt a)$. This is an elementary algebraic result : it is obvious that the quadratic form $X^2-aY^2-bZ^2$ represents $0$ iff $b$ is a norm from $K(\sqrt a)$; then it suffices to permute the variables $Y, Z$ .

2) **(Anti)-commutativity of the symbol.** There are at least two equivalent definitions of the Brauer group, via cohomology or via central simple algebras. Here the occurrence of cocycles with values $0,1$ seems to indicate that you opt for a cohomological definition, with *additive* notation for the values. But it is not a good idea to concentrate on calculations of cocycles, because after all the cohomological machinery functions with *cohomology groups* and their functorial properties. So, in the cohomological setting, the *absolute* Brauer group of $K$ is defined as $Br(K)=H^2(G_K, {K_{sep}}^*)$, which is the inductive limit of the *relative* Brauer groups $Br(L/K)=H^2(Gal(L/K), L^*)$ when $L$ runs through the finite Galois extensions of $K$.

For $a,b$ living in $K^*$ or in $K^*/{K^*}^2$ (check that it doesn't matter), your symbol $<a,b>$ for $a,b \in K^*$ is then a certain cohomology class in $Br(K)$ defined as the image of $(a,b)$ under the *cup-product* pairing $H^1(G_K, {\mu}_2) \times H^1(G_K, {\mu}_2) \to H^2(G_K, {\mu}_2)$, with  ${\mu}_2=(\pm 1)$ (*multiplicative* notation for the values). Without detailing the cup-product, let us make more precise the definition of the various terms. In the cohomology of the exact sequence $1\to {\mu}_2\to {K_{sep}}^*\to {K_{sep}}^*\to 1$ (taking squares in ${K_{sep}}^*$ is a surjective homomorphism), Hilbert's thm.90 says that $H^1(G_K, {K_{sep}}^*)=0$, hence  $H^1(G_K, {\mu}_2)\cong K^*/{K^*}^2 $, as well as $H^2(G_K, {\mu}_2)\cong Br(K)[2] $ (= the subgroup of elements killed by $2$). Moreover, because $G_K$ acts trivially on ${\mu}_2, H^1(G_K, {\mu}_2)= Hom(G_K, {\mu}_2)$ and the latter Hom group is $\cong K^*/{K^*}^2$ by Kummer theory. So finally, the cup-product induces a  pairing $(K^*/{K^*}^2)\times (K^*/{K^*}^2)\to Br(K)[2], (a,b)\to <a,b>$.
NB: The general cup-product with values in $(\mu_n$) is *anti-commutative*, i.e. $<a,b>={<b,a>}^{-1}$. It is commutative here only because the coefficients are in $\mu_2$. Anyway, the anti-commutativity also does the job in the general case.

3) $a$ **is a norm from** $K(\sqrt b)$ **iff**$<a,b>=1$. The functorial approach has also the advantage to explain why and how are introduced some notions/definitions which sometimes give the impression to fall from the sky. For more clarity, I tackle the general case when $K$ contains the group $\mu_n$ of $n$-th roots of unity, with $n$ not divisible by char($K$). Assume given a degree $n$ cyclic extension $L=K(\sqrt [n](a)/K$ with Galois group $G$, and the Kummer isomorphism $\phi: G \cong Hom (<a>$ mod ${K^*}^n, \mu_n)$ [$\phi$ is the same as in your first line when $n=2$]. Then the map $K^*\to  H^2(G, K^*)$ sending an element $b\in K^*$ to the class of the cyclic algebra $(\phi, b)$ induces an isomorphism $H^2(G, L^*)\cong K^*/N(L^*)$, where $N$ is the norm map . It follows immediately that $b$ is a norm from $K(\sqrt a)$ iff the cyclic algebra $(\phi, b)$ is split (i.e. is isomorphic to the matrix algebra $M_2(K)$). I don't recall the definition of $(\phi, b)$, but suffice it to say that for $n=2$ it coincides with the generalized quaternion algebra $(a,b)$ with basis {$1,i,j,ij$} defined by $i^2=a, j^2=b, ij=-ji$. Thus the functorial approach not only explains the intervention of $\phi$, but it also establishes a link between the two definitions of $Br(K)$  ./.

**Ref.** The best seems to be the book "Central simple algebras and Galois cohomology" by P. Gille & T. Szamuely, Cambridge Univ. Press, chap. 1 and 4.